Custom module views-view.html.twig output
I have a custom module that I want to provide certain out of the box functionality, and some of that is going to be pre-generated views inside of a /config folder.
I want to re-arrange some of the HTML for these views at the module level, assuming that I can then just overwrite that further on the theme level if I wish at a later point.
As I would normally do at theme level, I have created a /templates folder inside of my custom module (which I know it must be reading from as I have items within here referenced from inside a hook_theme function) but it just does not pick up any overwritten templates for my views displays. Is this even possible or does Drupal only look to pick up template suggestions from within themes?

This question is similar to: How to store Views templates with a module instead of a theme. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
